# Asp.net: How to add event handler referencing dynamically created elements

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net program that creates a simple survey form for users to answer. 
Most of the questions use a dropdownlist with answer scores from 1-5 (bad-good) and I'm trying to add an event handler to the dropdownlist objects so that the comments box is only enabled if the user selects a score between 1 and 2.

However when I add the delegate lambda call for the event handler, instead of each dropdownlist affecting their own corresponding comment box, they all seem to point only at the last one added (and they work once, then no more and only the last ddl continues having the expected behaviour).

My code:

```
   //Called from Page_Load
   private void PopulateSurvey()
   {
        btnSubmit.Enabled = true;
        List<Question> questions = (from p in context.Questions
                                    join q in context.Survey_Questions on p.ID equals q.QuestionID
                                    where q.SurveyID == surveyid
                                    select p).ToList();
        Table tbl = new Table();
        tbl.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        TableRow tr;
        TableCell tc;
        TableCell tc1;
        TableCell tc2;
        TextBox txt;
        CheckBox cbk;
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();

        foreach (Question q in questions)
        {

            if (q.Division.Equals("General") || q.Division.Equals(ddlDivisions.SelectedValue.ToString()))
            {
                tr = new TableRow();
                tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Width = Unit.Percentage(55);
                tc.Text = q.Text;
                tc.Attributes.Add("id", q.ID.ToString());
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                tc = new TableCell();

                if (q.QuestionType.ToLower() == "singlelinetextbox")
                {
                    txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.ID = "txt_" + q.ID;
                    //txt.Width = Unit.Percentage(40);
                    tc.Controls.Add(txt);
                }

                if (q.QuestionType.ToLower() == "multilinetextbox")
                {
                    txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.ID = "txt_" + q.ID;
                    txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                    //txt.Width = Unit.Percentage(40);
                    tc.Controls.Add(txt);
                }

                if (q.QuestionType.ToLower() == "singleselect")
                {
                    ddl = new DropDownList();
                    ddl.ID = "ddl_" + q.ID;
                    //ddl.Width = Unit.Percentage(41);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.Options))
                    {
                        string[] values = q.Options.Split(',');
                        foreach (string v in values)
                            ddl.Items.Add(v.Trim());
                    }
                    ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
                    tc.Controls.Add(ddl);
                }
                //tc.Width = Unit.Percentage(60);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);

                //Add comment row
                tc1 = new TableCell();
                //tc.Width = Unit.Percentage(5);
                tc1.Text = "Comentario: ";
                tc1.Attributes.Add("id", q.ID.ToString());
                //tc1.Visible = false;
                tr.Cells.Add(tc1);

                tc2 = new TableCell();
                txt = new TextBox();
                txt.ID = "txt_" + q.ID + "comment";
                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
                //txt.Width = Unit.Percentage(25);
                tc2.Controls.Add(txt);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc2);

                ddl.SelectedIndexChanged+= (sender, e) => ScoreChanged(sender, e, tc1,tc2, ddl.SelectedIndex);

                tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
        }
        pnlSurvey.Controls.Add(tbl);
    }

    protected void ScoreChanged (object sender, EventArgs e, TableCell tc1, TableCell tc2, int score)
    {
        if( score <2)
        {
            tc1.Visible = false;
            tc2.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            tc1.Visible = true;
            tc2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

First thing that comes to mind is maybe the event handler keeps the references themselves,m instead of the orphaned objects created with each question, so all event handlers end up with the same tc1 and tc2 reference and thus only the last object? Is that the case and if so how do I go around it?

Comment: Show the whole loop please. It sounds like all your handlers are sharing the same variable. After the loop completes (and they execute well after it completes, of course), its value is the last value you assigned to it. The way to fix this is by declaring those variables as locals in side the loop block, so each iteration will have its own copy.

Comment: `//Here I call the event handler.` -- no, there you **define** the event handler. Somebody else calls it, later on.

Comment: @EdPlunkett... Oh... Maybe that's the problem...?

Comment: Maybe what's the problem?

Comment: Your idea of declaring tc1 and tc2 inside the loop helped but not compeltely. Now, if I clikd on a ddl and change its value the appropriate combobox is affected once -- but if I try again nothing happens and only the last ddl works normally.

Comment: I got it. I had to move the ddl declaration into the loop as well. Thanks! Write that down below so I can accept it as an answer and give you credit please

Comment: ***Every*** variable that might be referenced in a lambda needs to be declared inside the loop. (Ha, bingo -- you submitted your last comment a second before this one -- good work nailing it!)

Comment: This is a duplicate, I've already answered it a few times elsewhere.

Comment: AH, I should delete it then, right? I couldn't find something similar but I wasn't really sure what to search for.

Comment: I just pasted your title into google and didn't get any other relevant results, so maybe keep it. Somebody will phrase it the way you did, and find the answer. You could find a duplicate to mark it as, or just answer it yourself if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged +=
    (sender, e) => ScoreChanged(sender, e, tc1,tc2, ddl.SelectedIndex);
```

Two things are important here:

- You are using an anonymous method to invoke `ScoreChanged`.
- You are passing `tc1` and `tc2` as an argument to the `ScoreChanged` method. You have defined those variables at the beginning of your code block, *outside* the loop.

The magic word in this context is **closure**. Since `tc1` and `tc2` are defined outside the scope of the anonymous method, they turn into closures. That means the will not have the value at the time you *define* the method, but at the time you *invoke* it. Since you are constantly overwriting the value of the variables in the `foreach` loop, at the time of the invokation those variables will have the value of the last iteration of the loop.

The solution is simple: Declare the variables *inside* the loop. This will create a new closure for each iteration of the `foreach`:

```
TableRow tr;
TableCell tc;
TextBox txt;
CheckBox cbk;

foreach (Question q in questions)
{
    TableCell tc1;
    TableCell tc2;
    DropDownList ddl; //Don't forget to include ddl, since you are using its selected index
    //...
```

On a more general note: Don't do "declaration" blocks like this at the beginning of a method in C#. Declare the variable the first time you use it (unless there is a good reason to do otherwise, for example you *want* it to be a part of a closure). There are many good reasons for that and you just have experienced one of them. Another one would be that when you turn a part of your code to a method with Visual Studio's refactoring feature, you will pass the predeclared variables as `ref` params. These are the most obvious reasons. There are more.